# Dropout and batchNormalization using "neuralnet" R library

Tags: r, neural-network, batch-normalization, dropout

I am using neuralnet R library for building my neural network. However, I did not have any success to implement drop out and batch normalization in my model architecture and I did not find anything in the documentation of this library. I would appreciate any help.

```
data("iris")
str(iris) 
indexes=createDataPartition(iris$Species, p=.85, list = F)
train = iris[indexes, ]
nnet=neuralnet(Species~., train, hidden = c(4,3), linear.output = FALSE)
```

So, in this example is there anyway to define dropout and batch normalization for getting a better accuracy? Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is not possible. I suggest to you to use a library like pytorch, keras or tensorflow.

Comment: That is what I thought too. In my defined task, I have to use this package, and I was wondering whether it is possible or not. Thanks for comment though!